# How to retrieve the value stored in localstorage?

Tags: javascript

```
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
        $checkboxes = $("#list :checkbox");

    $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
            checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
    });
```

I am using the code above to store the data into local storage.

```
{"2":false,"3":false,"4":true}
```

The data stored in the local storage. How can i get only the value 2 or false?
I want to collect the data in the local storage and stored into an array during submit the form.

```
var items=[];
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
            if(value===true){
                $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
                items.push(key);
            }
        });
```

The code seem like got problem during submit which caused integrity constraint duplicate entry when store the data to database. I am using ajax to post the data to server and store the data. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to access the `checkboxValues` object. You need to parse it.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkboxValues"));
```

To access "2", use `obj["2"]`.

```
var obj = {"2":false,"3":false,"4":true};
localStorage.setItem('checkboxValues',JSON.stringify(obj));
var storedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues'));
console.log(storedObject["2"]);
```

Comment: what if to get the value of key?

Comment: Didn't get the question, which key you want to access?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But i have problem when passing data to server.

Comment: Please share your problem. You need to stringify the object before sending it to server and parse it on server to access the object.

Comment: I am using $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {} to get the "true" value and push 'key' to the items array during submit and call ajax to post the data. But it only save the data where the current page active and data from another page with error integrity constraint duplicated entry.

Comment: Multiple checkboxes would have true value, it would be better if you could assign unique value to each checkbox and store it in your array when checkbox is clicked, then send it to server. This way you could identify the value and the associated checkbox.

Comment: Yeah, i am storing unique id, but still problem occurred.

Comment: The value true/false is only used to get id which has 'true' value and then store in to array and pass to server.

Comment: Store in an object as you are doing in the above question and then send the ids to server

Comment: But if i am not storing data in an object, it will caused problem? Because it able to pass the array from view to controller via ajax and error occurred as i mentioned.